# WPF Listbox doesn't add whole string

Tags: c#, wpf, cmd, listbox, listboxitem

I am trying to add multiple User to an active directory group via CMD commands and display the result.
I want to have the users listed in one listbox and next to it in another listbox the results, whether it worked or not.

```
for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
{
 System.Diagnostics.Process pProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
 string strCommand = "cmd.exe";
 string strCommandParameters = Parameters;
 pProcess.StartInfo.FileName = strCommand;
 pProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = strCommandParameters;
 pProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 pProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
 pProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
 pProcess.Start();

 string strOutput = pProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

 LBresponse.Items.Add(strOutput);
 Console.WriteLine(strOutput);

 pProcess.WaitForExit();
}
```

When I print the results with `Console.WriteLine(strOutput);`, I get these 3 lines out.

> System error 5 occurred.

> Access denied

> The request is processed on a ****

But when I try to add the string to the listbox with `LBresponse.Items.Add(strOutput);` only the last line is added.
The first two are a bit more important than the last one.

I think the problem is the loop, but I have no clue how to fix it.

Comment: nope! the problem is `ReadToEnd`. try a nested loop with `ReadLine`. Or try to implement a "multiline listview"

Comment: @Bizhan ```ReadLine``` didn´t solve it. Will look into "multiline listview"

Comment: How exactly it didn't solve it? what did you try?

Comment: Okay sorry, overlooked the "nested loop" part.

Comment: To understand the reason, check this output:Console.WriteLine(amount +": "+ strOutput);
And write the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that

```
pProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
string strOutput = pProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

must be replaced by

```
pProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
string strOutput = pProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
```

To get the first two lines out.

`ReadLine` will print out the first line.

Comment: Didn´t know that ```pProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput= true;``` will print the content in the console on it´s own.